# How to move a word to the next line in Sigil

Tags: epub

I know how to move words on the same line, but I don't know how to move them to the next line in the code view.  When I move the word over on the same line,  I increase the left: numbers.  I want to move the word "A" to the next line to correct an error at the beginning of the page.  I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance,

Janis

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a hard line-break within a paragraph use `<br />`. For example:

```
<p>First line<br />Second line</p>
```

Alternatively, insert `</p><p>`. For example:

```
<p>First line</p><p>Second line</p>
```

Comment: `<br/>` is also acceptable.